# Non-standard week numbering

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

I'm building an API for my college's timetable website. The default option is to look up today's timetable. However, the timetable system is using week numbering different to the one we normally use.

One of the 2 things I need to build the URL is the week number.

```
TIMETABLE_URL = 'http://timetable.ait.ie/reporting/textspreadsheet;student+set;id;{}?t=student+set+textspreadsheet&days=1-5&=&periods=3-20&=student+set+textspreadsheet&weeks={}&template=student+set+textspreadsheet'
```

Week numbering should start at this date: `27 Aug 2018 - 2 Sep 2018`. Following this, `week 2` would be `3 Sep 2018-9 Sep 2018` and so on. This should carry over  New Years, the date of `31 Dec 2018-6 Jan 2019`  would be `week 19`. This 'year' would have 52 weeks total.

I know how to check if a certain date is in between one of the ranges from above, but I want to avoid manually setting all the date ranges. How can I have a script know that, for example, it's in week 3 on 12 September?

Comment: What is your expected input and output? Is it a datetime object or string?

Comment: @KevinFang The expected output is the week number: for example, on 12 September the week number returned should be 3.

Comment: So you want a program that takes in a datetime object as the start date (e.g. 27 Aug 2018), and a current datetime object (e.g. 12 Sep 2018), and output an int 3, am I right?

Comment: @KevinFang Essentially, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `datetime.datetime` object:

```
from datetime import datetime
start = datetime.strptime('20180827', '%Y%m%d')
current = datetime.strptime('20180912', '%Y%m%d')
print((current - start).days//7 +1) # The week number
# Output: 3
```

This can also handle different years. Note that this only works when the start date is Monday.